# transform into ES5 syntax Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this syntax into ES5 syntax.

```
moveUp() {
    this.row > 0 ? this.row -= 1 : this.row = 0
  }
```

Comment: It already is ES5 syntax.

Comment: I cannot understand it then, how can I transform it into an easier syntax

Comment: @Pointy - Actually, ES5 didn't have method syntax. (I had to go check.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah you may be right, I read it as a plain (incorrect) function declaration. (Guessing context is always difficult here.)

Answer (score 1):

The only part of that that isn't ES5 is the fact it's a method declaration. I'm assuming this is in an object literal, like this:

```
const obj = {
    moveUp() {
        this.row > 0 ? this.row -= 1 : this.row = 0;
    }
};
```

If so, the near-equivalent in ES5 is to use a function expression in a property initializer:

```
const obj = {
    moveUp: function() {
        this.row > 0 ? this.row -= 1 : this.row = 0;
    }
};
```

---

Side note: I recommend not using the conditional operator purely for side-effects like that. It's an if/else thing, use `if`/`else` (in ES5 or ES2015+):

```
const obj = {
    moveUp: function() {
        if (this.row > 0) {
            --this.row;
        } else {
            this.row = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

It's also questionable whether you need the `else` at all. Presumably nothing assigns a negative number to `this.row`, so you could probably just do this:

```
const obj = {
    moveUp: function() {
        if (this.row > 0) {
            --this.row;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking an "easier syntax" add the `this.row = 0` to the else part of your if statement

```
moveUp(){
  if (this.row > 0){
    this.row -= 1
  } else {
    this.row = 0
  }
}
```

You can learn more about if statements here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp